# How to obtain a page's GUID in Composite C1 CMS?

Tags: cms, blog, rss

Question is pretty simple, I think.

How can I find out what the page GUID for a certain page in my [Composite C1](http://www.composite.net/) website is?

I need it for RSS reading from a Blog within the CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit \Composite\content\forms\Administrative\EditPage.xml and add:

```
      <TextBox Label="Id" Help="For internal usage" Type="readonly">
        <TextBox.Text>
          <cms:read source="SelectedPage.Id" />
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

so you will see page id during the editing.

Comment: Thank you! This seems a lot easier than where I found them eventually, which was in the DataStores!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the ID of a page is to create a link to it (in the Visual Editor or a code editor) and then either switch to code view or view link properties. There you will see the GUID.